# Elixir doctest fails for function that returns random values

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

I have a function in Elixir that produces three random RGB tuples in a list.

```
defmodule Color do



  @doc """
  Create three random r,g,b colors as a list of three tuples

  ## Examples

      iex> colors = Color.pick_color()
      iex> colors
      [{207, 127, 117}, {219, 121, 237}, {109, 101, 206}]

  """
      def pick_color() do
        color = Enum.map((0..2), fn(x)->
          r = Enum.random(0..255)
          g = Enum.random(0..255)
          b = Enum.random(0..255)
          {r, g, b}
        end)
end
```

When I run my tests, my doctests fail. The resulting list of tuples are different than what is defined in my doctest. How can I write a doctest for a function that returns a random value?

Comment: You can't. You can only doctest pure functions.

Comment: @JustinWood you can make `Enum.random` deterministic by setting a seed value (see my answer). :)

Comment: You can (at least now) use pattern matching in doctests too: `iex> [_a, _b, {_r, 121, _b}] = Color.pick_color()`, just don't put an expected return value the line after. Test output will be prettyfied for this in case of an error as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to test a function with doctests, **you must be able to predict the output of your function**. In this case, you can't predict the output of your function.

---

However you could test your function with regular tests.

Here is a test that would make sure `Color.pick_color()` produces a list of 3 tuples, using pattern matching:

```rb
test "pick color" do
  [{_, _, _}, {_, _, _}, {_, _, _}] = Color.pick_color()
end
```

You could also check if each value is between `0` and `255`, etc.

Comment: I did fall back to a regular test. But thank you for explaining the limits of doc tests :)

Answer (score 7):

You can make the random functions deterministic by setting the seed of `:rand`'s random number generator. [This is also how `Enum.random/1` is tested in Elixir.](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/a87046a2cfa406e1bd63beba9c438eb61b8fa0bc/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L1776-L1783)

First, open `iex` and set the seed of the current process to any value:

```
iex> :rand.seed(:exsplus, {101, 102, 103})
```

Then, run your function in `iex`

```
iex> Color.pick_color()
```

Now just copy this value into your doctest along with the `:rand.seed` call. By explicitly setting the seed, you're going to get the same values from the functions in `:rand` module and `Enum.random/1` uses `:rand` internally.

```
iex(1)> :rand.seed(:exsplus, {1, 2, 3})
iex(2)> for _ <- 1..10, do: Enum.random(1..10)
[4, 3, 8, 1, 6, 8, 1, 6, 7, 7]
iex(3)> :rand.seed(:exsplus, {1, 2, 3})
iex(4)> for _ <- 1..10, do: Enum.random(1..10)
[4, 3, 8, 1, 6, 8, 1, 6, 7, 7]
iex(5)> :rand.seed(:exsplus, {1, 2, 3})
iex(6)> for _ <- 1..10, do: Enum.random(1..10)
[4, 3, 8, 1, 6, 8, 1, 6, 7, 7]
```

Comment: impressive haha. Thank you. I will definitely look into this more.